# Question about "death grip on something"

Tags: word-meaning

> The other thing is our hand position when we’re driving. It’s nice, soft hands are very important in learning to drive. We don’t want a **death grip on** that wheel. We want nice, soft hands, like pretty much anything that you do in sports, your hands have to be nice and soft. If your hands are soft and you’re not real tense, you’ll find that you have the ability to steer a car much, much better.

What does the word **grip** mean here? What does it mean to say **to want a death grip on something** ?

Comment: Have you looked up the phrase "[death grip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_grip)"? [This one](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/death%20grip) might be more helpful to you.

Comment: @Cat Wow. Even I didn't expect to find *death grip* in a dictionary How many dictionaries did you consult? [Onelook](http://onelook.com/?w=Death+grip&ls=a) returns zero useful returns for a learner. It can return results in the twenties.

Comment: @pazzo I consulted the dictionary called "the Google". Search: [definition "death grip"](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+%22death+grip%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) gives several results.

Comment: One can certainly find *grip* in a dictionary. I don't find the meaning of  *death grip* to be intuitively obvious or transparent to learners, at least of certain levels. As per my comment before this one, it is also almost impossible to find in a dictionary.

Comment: @Cat Okay, but are we now expecting all English learners to know how to do definition searches in search engines?

Comment: @pazzo I'm sorry, I'm confused... I never search any other way, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Many native speakers are unaware of this function. And a regular Google search for "death grip" isn't that useful. So I am asking if expecting all learners of English to know how to do the type of search you did is realistic, or that it should be considered something that users are supposed to know about.

Comment: @pazzo If a search was attempted and it was unhelpful it would be nice to see that some effort had been made. I search for "define <bolded phrase>" using Duck Duck Go just to see how difficult it is to find answers and how ambiguous they are before I close vote. It's not a Google function,  and I don't think expecting some sort of effort to find an answer before asking is unreasonable.

Comment: Duck Duck Go? How many learners know about it? If I ever heard of it, I forgot about it long ago. My method is to input on Google: death grip define (without punctuation). There are some dictionary returns, some not so great returns (including UD), and terribly irrelevant/confusing  returns. Frankly, right now this is becoming a discussion about which search techniques we should expect learners to be aware of, not a measure of have they tried or not

Comment: No-one mentioned yet that the quote itself appears to be written by someone who doesn't write for a living. The whole piece looks like it was written by a plumber - with apologies to all plumbers with a good 'grip' on English - 'soft'? really? [& 'real tense'… puhlease…]

Comment: @pazzo I mentioned an alternate search engine to illustrate  (poorly perhaps ) that it's not just a Google thing. Regardless,  if any type of search was attempted, it's not apparent from the question and closing it until we have more information about why a search didn't help is a reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

[Grip](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grip?s=t) is an odd word to define.  It refers to the strength which you're holding onto something with your hands.

**death grip** is an idiom that essentially "very strong grip".

The phrase *We don't want a death grip on that wheel* essentially translates to we don't want to hold onto the wheel very hard.